# Connection protected when I want to see my item in detail Laravel

Tags: laravel, database, controller, show, laravel-9

I am on laravel 9, I have my database with my element that I want to see in detail but it shows me this when I want to see it, (I see it when I want to display all the elements)

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDIsQ.png)

Controller

```
public function show(Tickets $tickets)
{
    var_dump($tickets);
    return view('tickets.show', ['ticket' => $tickets]);
}
```

Models

```
class Tickets extends Model
{
use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;




protected $fillable = [
    'title',
    'description',
    'status',
    'priority',
    'type',
    'assigned_to',
];

}
```

Routes

```
Route::get('oauth', [gCalendarController::class, 'oauth']);
```

Comment: that is the dump of that object ... what do you actually want to see? if you just return the model (which is an empty non existing instance) you would get the serialized JSON version (which doesn't have attributes)

Comment: for exemple Hello, "{{ $tickets->title }}" i would like see title of tickets with id 1

Answer (score 0):

I think you returned the object of Tickets Model like @lagbox commented.

If you want to get all ticket when accessing to show() function, you need to do like this:

```php
public function show(Tickets $tickets)
{
    // Get all the ticket
    $ticket = $tickets->all();

    return view('tickets.show', compact('ticket'));
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: This method return all tickets but i would like one ticket, if my routes is tickets/1 i would like only tickets with id 1

Comment: //not running
Route::Resource('tickets', TicketsController::class);
//running
Route::get('/tickets/{tickets}', [TicketsController::class, 'show']);